# How the tackle this limited integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, curves

I started with use of a new variable for the things under square root.

I would like to calculate the integral 
$$\iint_\Omega\sqrt{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}~\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}y$$
over the respected area
$$\Omega=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2;x\geq 0,y\geq 0,\sqrt x+\sqrt y\leq 1\}$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Transform variables from $(x,y)$ to $(u,v)$ where $x=u^2$ and $y=v^2$.  The Jacobian of transformation is $4uv$ so that

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{\left(1-\sqrt{y}\right)^2}\sqrt{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}\,dx\,dy=4\int_0^1\,v\,\left(\int_0^{1-v}\,u\,\sqrt{u+v}\,du\right)\,dv$$

Comment: The bounds for $x$ should be $0 \le x \le (1-\sqrt{y})^2$ instead of $0 \le x \le 1-\sqrt{y}$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Thanks for that catch!  + 1 for your comment.  I edited accordingly.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can. - Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV If I am not mistaken it seems that one can actually go further. If you first substitute $w=u+v$ and then ${w=r^2}$ then the integral can be calculated.

Comment: @urgje Notice the bold-faced, capitalized wird, HINT, that begins the post.  The integral can be carried out in the $u-v$ coordinates directly and is rather straightforward.  That is an exercise for the reader.

Comment: still I can not get any further